# Angular 6: Cannot find name 'Iterable' 'Map' 'Set'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am generating a basic Angular 6 project using the CLI and it works just fine, but at a certain point these d.ts errors appear (See picture below) and they never go away, even thought the solution still builds and runs without a problem. Anyone experienced this and knows how to get rid of them?

[image]

**Environment:**

- Visual Studio 2017
- Angular 6 generated with CLI
- Bootstrap 4 installed with `ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics`

**Edit**

Below is my tsconfig.json (It's the default one generated by the CLI):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: typescript issue. did you enable polyfill?

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: A more appropriate way to install it is using [`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#installation) instead of the command that you've used.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I don't think so. Angular CLI uses the default package manager install command if the desire package has no angular schematics.

Comment: I did not touch anything polyfill related after generated the project with the CLI